# How do I declare a static const struct in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an `LEDControl` class which sets the color of an LED using a method.
Many classes use this `LEDControl` class to pass it some colors to assign to an LED. Therefore, I wanted to define the colors somewhere as a constant.

I thought I'd make a struct in my `LEDControl` class called `Color`, since I really only need to access the members directly and never anything else:

```
struct Color{
    bool r;
    bool g;
    bool b;
};
```

I then added a #define in the .cpp

```
#define RED Color{true, false, false};
```

But this didn't work; it is not declared in the scope of any other class.

What can I do to store a set of colors somewhere in my program so that every class using the `LEDControl` can use keywords or variable names like RED and GREEN?

Comment: Use class enums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining global constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268749/defining-global-constant-in-c)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, #defines are evil.  if you really want to do something make a `const Color red{}` but this isn't really what you want either...

Comment: Unless you include the header that defines `Color`, you can't use it. There is no portable way to make an identifier "globally available".

Comment: Wonder why the down voters did so ... they didn't seem to comment on why.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using macros, provide `inline constexpr` instances of your `struct`:

```
namespace color
{
    inline constexpr Color red{true, false, false};
    inline constexpr Color green{false, true, false};
    inline constexpr Color blue{false, false, true};
}
```

You can provide these in an header file so that they will be accessible from any file including it.

Comment: is `inline` variables live yet? thought it was for '17

Comment: Where would I define the struct itself?

Comment: @Zimano: anywhere you want, as long as it's before the `red`/`green`/`blue` definitions and visible there.

Comment: @sp2danny: yes, `inline` is in 17.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo And the namespace I define in a separate header, right?

Comment: @Zimano: sure. You can define it anywhere you want. If you want multiple `.cpp` files to use it, define it in an header and include it in every `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

put the definition in a header. Please avoid `#define`
it could look like:

```
static constexpr Color RED{true, false, false};
```

Comment: That `static` is unnecessary, actually.