# constant variables that are used only in one cpp file - where to declare them

Tags: c++, static, constants

I have a small project and all its code is in one namespace (multiple files), in certain file I need to use multiple constants.

Only this one file will use those constant variables.

Which one is the right way to go and what's the difference (I'm familiar with static and const but still don't know the difference)

1. declare static const in the header, define in the source file
2. define const in source file in the namespace scope
3. define static const in source file in the namespace scope

Comment: Declare it with the least needed scope and visibility.

Comment: 4. Define them in an anonymous namespace in the file that uses them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining global constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268749/defining-global-constant-in-c)

Comment: or maybe `constexpr`

Comment: it's not a duplication of because I don't want it to be visible in multiple source files but only in this one source file in different functions.
P.S
constexpr is not an options because it's not c++11

Comment: If you need them in one source file only keep them local to that file. I would go for number 3.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon - what's the difference between 2 and 3, both are local to that file

Comment: can you change the question to be less subjective? What is prefered is mainly opinion-based, but maybe you can make it more explicit by saying what piece of information you are missing to decide between the options you list

Comment: @molbdnilo would upvote that if it were an answer.

Comment: @zonzor18 • 2 and 3 are the same.  3 is a little more typing.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon • 2 has internal linkage too, because it is a const and isn't declared `extern`.

Comment: @Eljay Whoops, you are right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Only this one file will use those constant variables.

If I understood correctly, that sentence automatically excludes the first option:

> declare static const in the header, define in the source file

You don't need to expose the declaration in other compilation units (*cpp* files), so you don't need a header file includable in different cpp files.

---

At this point the following options:

> 2. define const in source file in the namespace scope
> 3. define static const in source file in the namespace scope

**In your situation, the correct answer should be (3).**

---

#### Why?

The answer is simply the correlation with the meaning of `static` variable *outside function block*.

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

> The static specifier [...]. When used in a declaration at namespace scope, it specifies internal linkage.

So when you need to declare a constant variable which will be used only in that single compilation unit (cpp file), you *should* declare it as `static const` in order to express the *internal linkage* more explicit in the reading.

---

#### Extra

[In general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) is a good point to use, instead, an *anonymous namespace* in your compilation unit.

In your `.cpp` file:

```
 namespace {
    const int kVariable = 12;
 }

 // no more static const int kVariable = 12;

 void foo() {
   std::cout << kVariable << '\n';
 }
```

The purpose is practically the same.

---

#### Conclusions

All those information give you a general idea about `static` keyword in the constant declarations.

Anyway, it is often a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

I'd select option #3.  It is a little more typing, and means the same thing as #2.

But people (myself included!) can easily forget that a `const` will have internal linkage unless declared `extern const`.  So putting `static const` helps with self-documenting code, in my opinion.

If you like anonymous namespaces, you could put them in one to help clarify that they are internal to that translation unit.  That is a matter of preference.