# Why does std::is_literal_type<std::String> == false and how can I get around it?

Tags: c++, string, global-variables, inline, constexpr

I'm currently trying to use `constexpr` to define some input identification stuff:

```
struct RangeParams {
    string legacyId;
    string fullname;
    string shortname;
    float min = -1; 
    float baseline = 0;
    float max = 1;
    float defaultValue = 0;
};

...

inline constexpr RangeParams curve1 = { "some_id", "my_name", ...};
```

Unfortunately, I get an error for the constexpr line saying

> Constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const RangeParams'

So, I dug into it to figure out what part of this is non-literal, and `string` was the culprit.

```
std::cout << std::is_literal_type<float>::value;  // output: 1
std::cout << std::is_literal_type<string>::value;  // output: 0
```

Finding this has highlighted an important fact for me which is that my understanding of literal-types is rather flawed.  For the most part, I'd simply thought of them as being the basics (numbers, strings, booleans, structs made of those things).

So why would a simple string not be a literal type?  What's the gotcha here?

Also, how can I get around this?  I'm trying to make a global out of my RangeParams and the most modern answer to this question ([Defining global constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268749/defining-global-constant-in-c)) appears not be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` is not a literal. `const char[]` is. The gotcha is that a `std::string` is a container of a dynamic size. No, you can't get around this and still use `std::string`. `std::string` is unusable in constexpr context.

You might want to replace `std::string` with `const char*` in your code:

```
struct RangeParams {
    const char* legacyId;
    const char* fullname;
    const char* shortname;
    float min = -1; 
    float baseline = 0;
    float max = 1;
    float defaultValue = 0;
};
```

It's not exactly the same, but given the lack of context, it's hard to justify what did you exactly need the `std::string` for, thus it's uncertain that a `const char*` will be a suitable alternative.

EDIT: A short example should help to understand the misconception. What is the type of `0`?. It's an `int`. What's the type of `'a'`? It's a `char`. What's the type of `"abc"`? It's not `std::string`, it's `const char[4]`!